# Protocol extension in swift

Tags: swift

My goal is:

All the UIViewController witch adopt the Scrollable protocol and have a UIScrollView as a subView handle the scrollView insets according to the keyboard.

Any idea about the error in my code ? :

> Scrollable is not a subtype of UIViewController

```
import Foundation

protocol Scrollable {
    var scrollview: UIScrollView { get }
    func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

extension Scrollable where Self: UIViewController {

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(Self, selector: #selector(Scrollable.keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(Self, selector: #selector(Scrollable.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification", object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (aNotification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
            scrollview.contentInset = contentInsets
            scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        scrollview.contentInset = contentInsets
        scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    }
}
```

Comment: You have created `UIScrollView` extension and derived it from `UIViewController` thats why it throws error. change it to `extension Scrollable where
UIScrollView`.

Comment: I want all my UIViewController witch have a UIScrollView handle the keyboard show/hide. Not the scrollView

Comment: It's not a UIScrollView extension.

Comment: Can the down voter explain why, pls ?

Comment: Provide details what is your expected result and whats not working.

Comment: It's clear. I want all the UIViewController witch adopt the Scrollable protocol and have a UIScrollView as a subView handle the scrollView insets according to the keyboard.

Comment: refer this [github gist](https://github.com/vitkuzmenko/Swift-Extensions/blob/master/UIScrollView%2BExtension.swift).

Comment: Now you provided reason, better keep it in question so everyone get better understanding of it.

Comment: Did you try to import UIKit?

Comment: I don't know about down vote, but whenever you ask question make sure to provide enough information, You are aware about the problem but others are not, its good habit to put enough information for others.